# Auto updating entire DataTable on when data was inserted or updated

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am having difficulty rendering a PrimeFaces Datatable once a row data has been inserted or updated. It is not updating in the datatable or edit dialog when opened.It is showing older values. When the server is stopped and started the application it displays the new values in datatable or edit dialog. 
I am migrating it from primefaces 2.2.1 to primefaces 6.1.

Here's the Updated JSF page:

```
<h:form id="dbform">
<p:growl id="growl" />
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="ADD New Data"
        onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" render="tbl"
        update="dialogfrom:newdevice" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
        immediate="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGroup id="dbpanelgrid">
    <p:dataTable style="width:800px;" id="tbl" var="med"
        value="#{seniorAction.searchResults}" paginator="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowKey="#{med.empNo}"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{seniorAction.selectedData}"
        rowClasses="table-evenRow,table-oddRow" rows="5"
        rowSelectListener="#{seniorAction.onDataSelect}" filteredValue="#{seniorAction.filteredEmployeeList}">
        <p:column sortBy="#{med.empNo}" filterBy="#{med.empNo}"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="EMPNO." />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{med.empNo}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="EMP TYPE " />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{med.empType}"
                styleClass="capitalized" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="CATEGORY TYPE " />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{med.catgryType}"
                styleClass="capitalized" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="DOCA" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{med.doca}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="text-align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="EDIT" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton title="EDIT"
                onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" render="tbl"
                action="#{seniorAction.editEmpNoDetails}"
                icon="ui-icon-pencil" update="editfrom:editdevice"
                immediate="true">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{med}"
                    target="#{seniorAction.selectedData}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="text-align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="DELETE" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton update="@form,dbform:tbl"
                title="DELETE" action="#{seniorAction.deleteEmpNo}"
                render="tbl" icon="ui-icon-trash" immediate="true">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{med}"
                    target="#{seniorAction.selectedData}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <!-- Delete Dialog box -->
    <!-- Preview Dialog box -->
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" />
<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="ADD New Data"
modal="true" widgetVar="dlg1" width="960" height="500"
hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
<h:form id="dialogfrom">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" id="newdevice">
        <h:outputLabel for="empno" value="EMPNO *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.empNo}"
            id="empno" required="true" maxlength="4" size="4">
            <f:validateLength maximum="4" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="NAME *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.name}"
            id="name" required="true" styleClass="capitalized"
            maxlength="40" size="40">
            <f:validateLength maximum="40" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="gender" value="GENDER *" />
        <h:selectOneRadio id="gender"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.gender}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="MALE" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="FEMALE" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:outputLabel for="caste" value="CATEGORY *" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="caste"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.casteCatgry}"
            required="true">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select Category--"
                noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="UR" itemLabel="UR" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="OBC" itemLabel="OBC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="SC" itemLabel="SC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="ST" itemLabel="ST" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="ESM" itemLabel="ESM" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/VH" itemLabel="PH/VH" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/OH" itemLabel="PH/OH" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/HH" itemLabel="PH/HH" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/VH/OBC"
                itemLabel="PH/VH/OBC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/OH/OBC"
                itemLabel="PH/OH/OBC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/HH/OBC"
                itemLabel="PH/HH/OBC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/VH/SC"
                itemLabel="PH/VH/SC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/VH/ST"
                itemLabel="PH/VH/ST" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/OH/SC"
                itemLabel="PH/OH/SC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/OH/ST"
                itemLabel="PH/OH/ST" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/HH/SC"
                itemLabel="PH/HH/SC" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="PH/HH/ST"
                itemLabel="PH/HH/ST" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="dob" value="DOB *" />
        <p:calendar id="dob" readonlyInput="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.dob}"
            maxdate="#{seniorAction.today}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            showOn="button" required="true" navigator="true">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="doj" />
        </p:calendar>
        <h:outputLabel for="desg" value="DESGINATION *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.desg}"
            id="desg" required="true" styleClass="capitalized"
            maxlength="40" size="40">
            <f:validateLength maximum="40" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="desgtype" value="DESG TYPE *" />
        <h:selectOneRadio id="desgtype"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.empType}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Officers"
                itemValue="OFFICERS" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Staff" itemValue="STAFF" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:outputLabel for="emptype" value="EMP TYPE *" />
        <h:selectOneRadio id="emptype"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.catName}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="General" itemValue="GENERAL" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Finance" itemValue="FINANCE" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Staff" itemValue="" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:outputLabel for="seniority" value="SENIORITY *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.senioritySno}"
            id="seniority" required="true" maxlength="4" size="4">
            <f:validateLength maximum="4" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="senioritytype"
            value="SENIORITY BY TYPE *" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="senioritytype" immediate="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.catgryType}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
            <f:selectItems id="options1"
                value="#{seniorAction.typeNames}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="qual" value="QUALIFICATION *" />
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{seniorAction.empNo.qual}"
            id="qual" required="true" maxlength="200" rows="5"
            cols="40" autoResize="false" style="resize: none">
            <f:validateLength maximum="200" />
        </p:inputTextarea>
        <h:outputLabel for="doj" value="DOJ *" />
        <p:calendar id="doj" readonlyInput="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.doj}"
            mindate="#{seniorAction.dob}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            showOn="button" required="true" navigator="true">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" />
        </p:calendar>
        <h:outputLabel for="doca" value="DOCA *" />
        <p:calendar id="doca"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.doca}"
            maxdate="#{seniorAction.today}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            showOn="button" required="true" navigator="true" />
        <h:outputLabel for="branch" value="BRANCH *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.branch}"
            id="branch" required="true" maxlength="30" size="30"
            styleClass="capitalized">
            <f:validateLength maximum="30" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="payscale" value="PAYSCALE *" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="payscale" immediate="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.empNo.payscale}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
            <f:selectItems id="options2"
                value="#{seniorAction.diffPayScales}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="otherdes" value="OTHER DES *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{seniorAction.empNo.otherDes}"
            id="otherdes" maxlength="30" size="30"
            styleClass="capitalized">
            <f:validateLength maximum="30" />
        </p:inputText>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Submit"
                update="@form,dbform:tbl" 
                actionListener="#{seniorAction.dataInsertion}"
                oncomplete="handleDialog(xhr, status, args)"
                onclick="javascript:void(0)" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
            <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel"
                update=":dialogfrom" onclick="PF('dlg1').hide();"
                type="reset" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleDialog(
        xhr,
        status,
        args) {
    if (args.validationFailed) {
        jQuery(
                '#basicDialog')
                .effect(
                        "shake",
                        {
                            times : 3
                        },
                        100);
    } else {
        PF('dlg1')
                .hide();
    }
}
</script>
<p:growl id="editgrowl" />
<p:dialog id="editDialog"
header="Edit Master Data Details" widgetVar="dlg2"
modal="true" width="480" height="620"
hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
<h:form id="editfrom">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" id="editdevice">
        <h:outputLabel for="empno" value="EMP NO" />
        <p:inputText id="empno"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.empNo}"
            readonly="true" size="4">
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="NAME" />
        <p:inputText id="name"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.name}"
            maxlength="40" size="40">
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="desg" value="DESGINATION" />
        <p:inputText id="desg"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.desg}"
            maxlength="40" size="40">
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="empType" value="EMP TYPE" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="empType" immediate="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.empType}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
            <f:selectItems id="options1"
                value="#{seniorAction.empTypeNames}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="catgryType" value="CATEGORY TYPE" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="catgryType" immediate="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.catgryType}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
            <f:selectItems id="options2"
                value="#{seniorAction.typeNames}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="seniority" value="SENIORITY SNO" />
        <p:inputText id="seniority"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.senioritySno}"
            maxlength="4" size="4" type="int">
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="qual" value="QUALIFICATION" />
        <p:inputTextarea id="qual"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.qual}"
            maxlength="200" rows="5" cols="40" autoResize="false"
            style="resize: none">
        </p:inputTextarea>
        <h:outputLabel for="branch" value="BRANCH" />
        <p:inputText id="branch"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.branch}"
            maxlength="30" size="30">
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="doca" value="DOCA" />
        <p:calendar id="doca"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.doca}"
            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" showOn="button" required="true"
            maxdate="#{seniorAction.selectedData.currentDate}"
            navigator="true" />
        <h:outputLabel for="payscale" value="PAYSCALE" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="payscale" immediate="true"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.payscale}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
            <f:selectItems id="options3"
                value="#{seniorAction.diffPayScales}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="otherdes" value="OTHER DES" />
        <p:inputText id="otherdes"
            value="#{seniorAction.selectedData.otherDes}"
            maxlength="30" size="30">
        </p:inputText>
        <f:facet name="footer" align="center">
            <p:commandButton id="conform" value="Update"
                actionListener="#{seniorAction.detailsModification}"
                update="dbform:tbl,:editgrowl"
                oncomplete="handleEditDialog(xhr, status, args)"
                onclick="javascript:void(0)" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
            <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel"
                update=":editgrowl" onclick="PF('dlg2').hide()"
                type="reset" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleEditDialog(
        xhr,
        status,
        args) {
    if (args.validationFailed) {
        jQuery(
                '#editDialog')
                .effect(
                        "shake",
                        {
                            times : 3
                        },
                        100);
    } else {
        PF('dlg2')
                .hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

And here's the backing bean:

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "seniorAction")
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class SeniorityAction {
        SeniorityService snService = new SeniorityService();
        private Collection<SeniorityData> searchResults;
        private SeniorityData selectedData;
        private SeniorityData empNo;
        private Collection<String> typeNames;
        private Collection<String> empTypeNames;
        private Collection<String> diffPayScales;
        private Date doj;
        private Date dob;
        private Date currentDate = new Date();

        public SeniorityAction() throws SQLException {
            searchResults = snService.getAllData();
            typeNames = snService.getTypeNames();
            empTypeNames = snService.getEmpTypeNames();
            diffPayScales = snService.getDiffPayScales();
            empNo = new SeniorityData();

            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            doj = c1.getTime();
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            dob = c2.getTime();
        }

        public Collection<SeniorityData> getSearchResults() {
            return searchResults;
        }

        public void setSearchResults(Collection<SeniorityData> searchResults)
                throws SQLException {
            this.searchResults = snService.getAllData();
        }

        public SeniorityData getSelectedData() {
            return selectedData;
        }

        public void setSelectedData(SeniorityData selectedData) {
            this.selectedData = selectedData;
        }

        public Collection<String> getTypeNames() {
            return typeNames;
        }

        public void setTypeNames(Collection<String> typeNames) {
            this.typeNames = typeNames;
        }

        public Collection<String> getEmpTypeNames() {
            return empTypeNames;
        }

        public void setEmpTypeNames(Collection<String> empTypeNames) {
            this.empTypeNames = empTypeNames;
        }

        public Collection<String> getDiffPayScales() {
            return diffPayScales;
        }

        public void setDiffPayScales(Collection<String> diffPayScales) {
            this.diffPayScales = diffPayScales;
        }

        public void deleteEmpNo() throws SQLException {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            boolean result = searchResults.remove(snService
                    .deleteEmpNo(selectedData.getEmpNo()));
            if (result == false) {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Master data deleted successfully"));
            } else {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Master data delete error"));
            }
        }

        public void editEmpNoDetails() throws SQLException {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Collection<SeniorityData> result = snService
                    .editEmpNoDetails(selectedData.getEmpNo());
            if (result != null) {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Master data updated successfully"));
            } else {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Error in updating Master data"));
            }
        }

        public void detailsModification() throws SQLException {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String result = snService.dataModification(selectedData);
            if (result != null) {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Master data for employee no " + selectedData.getEmpNo()
                                + " is modified successfully"));
            } else {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Error in Master data modification"));
            }

        }

        public void dataInsertion() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            String result = snService.newDataInsertion(empNo);

            if (result != null) {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Added new data successfully"));
            } else {
                context.addMessage("deviceID", new FacesMessage(
                        "Error in adding new data"));
            }
        }

        public SeniorityData getEmpNo() {
            return empNo;
        }

        public void setEmpNo(SeniorityData empNo) {
            this.empNo = empNo;
        }

        public void onDataSelect(SelectEvent event) throws SQLException {
            searchResults = snService.getAllData();
        }

        public String dataModification(SeniorityData selectedData) {
            ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
            Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String query = "update seniority_master set name =\""
                    + selectedData.getName().toUpperCase() + "\"," + "desg =\""
                    + selectedData.getDesg().toUpperCase() + "\"," + "seniority=\""
                    + selectedData.getSenioritySno() + "\"," + "emptype=\""
                    + selectedData.getEmpType() + "\"," + "type=\""
                    + selectedData.getCatgryType() + "\"," + "qual=\""
                    + selectedData.getQual().toUpperCase() + "\"," + "branch=\""
                    + selectedData.getBranch().toUpperCase() + "\"," + "doca=\""
                    + selectedData.getDocaFormatted() + "\"," + "payscale=\""
                    + selectedData.getPayscale() + "\"," + "otherdesc=\""
                    + selectedData.getOtherDes().toUpperCase()
                    + "\" where empno = '" + selectedData.getEmpNo() + "'";
            try {
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
                pool.freeConnection(connection);
            }
            return query;
        }

        public Date getToday() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            return c.getTime();
        }

        public void setToday(Date today) {
        }

        public Date getDoj() {
            return doj;
        }

        public void setDoj(Date doj) {
            this.doj = doj;
        }

        public Date getDob() {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob(Date dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
            if (doj.before(dob)) {
                doj = dob;
            }
        }

        public Date getCurrentDate() {
            return currentDate;
        }

        public void setCurrentDate(Date currentDate) {
            this.currentDate = currentDate;
        }

        public String getDojFormatted() {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return df.format(doj);
        }

        public String getDobFormatted() {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return df.format(dob);
        }
    }
```

The data which is inserted or deleted in the datatable are not reflecting.

Comment: Can you please specify your problem? What does not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: not getting any errors, but the datatable is not updating after inserting or editing a row, the edit dialog is not reflecting the updated values, delete of row is not reflecting in datatable, but all the CURD operations are reflecting in database

Comment: What actions do you take to update the table?

Comment: @T.Grottker seniorAction.dataInsertion for data insertion, seniorAction.editEmpNoDetails for data updation,seniorAction.deleteEmpNo for deletion of records

Comment: There's a lot going on on that page -you'll debug better by simplifying it. Start by looking at your browser's console when you perform the rowselect, to observe any js errors that are almost certainly causing your problems (if the backing bean action is being executed properly like you say)

Comment: @kolossus There is no issue with javascript which working fine. It is used only for validation of insertion and updation dialog,which shakes thrice if validation fails. I think it is problem of updation or rendering of data in the datatable i.e something need to modified or addition is required in datatable and command buttons.

Comment: You're missing the point: the ajax update and rerender still happens via JavaScript, just not your own JavaScript. Look in the console and see what it's telling you.

Comment: @kolossus checked in the console no errors are found while editing or adding or deletion of records. i have removed the ajax in my xhtml page. Updated my question

Comment: @kolossus while testing i found that when sorting the empno, the last number which is 9000 came top i modified the data then it is updating on datatable, but delete is not updating. And when filtering the data for same 9000 and editing it is not rendering the updated value in datatable and dialog.

Comment: @T.Grottker,@kolossus the edit on datatable is reflecting while performing by sort and filter option, but insertion and deletion are not reflecting in the datatable. This my updated code

Comment: Always, always, always create a [mcve]. Helps ypu narrowing down the problem and us spotting potential causes. And where did ypu read PF `p:commandLink\Button` has a `render` attribute?

Comment: @Kukeltje I already used render attribute in command button for primefaces 2.2.1

Comment: Sure it did something useful? Check the docs. It's non-existent